# Hide out of stock configurable product options in color swatches

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, configurable-swatches

I'm trying to set configurable swatches for an attribute I use to create configurable products. I've prepared all required images for available options, placed them in wysiwyg/swatches folder.

Before enabling swatches from config, only "in stock" options is getting displayed in dropdown, out of stock products are hidden. After enabling swatches, all in stock and out of stock products are getting displayed one by one. I want  to hide not available options and only display available ones.

I've checked magento release notes (see in link below) and I guess they made a change in 1.9.3.0 to diplay all available options consistenly. How can I revert this?

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1934